# Class serialization issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, class, serialization

I have an error in the the following class, but am unsure where it is. The class will return correctly in my service but does not serialize and return any results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Objects
Imports System.Data.Objects.DataClasses
Imports System.Data.EntityClient
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

' <summary>  
'<para>This class is used to load Email objects.</para>  
' <para>
' CreateDate: 6-14-2011
' ModifyDate: 6-14-2011
' ModifyDesc: Initial Creation
' </para>
' </summary>  
' 
#Region "Email"
''' <summary>
''' Email class.
''' </summary>
<DataContractAttribute(IsReference:=True)>
<KnownTypeAttribute(GetType(CompanyLocEmail))>
<KnownTypeAttribute(GetType(CompanyEmail))>
<KnownTypeAttribute(GetType(UserEmail))>
Partial Public MustInherit Class Email

    #Region "Declarations"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Private _IsPreferred As Nullable(Of Global.System.Boolean)
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Private _EmailTypeL As Global.System.String
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Private _EmailTypeS As Global.System.String
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Private _EmailAddress As Global.System.String
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Private _XID As Global.System.Int32
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Private _EID As Global.System.Int32
    #End Region

    #Region "Primitive Properties"
    #Region "IsPreferred"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' IsPrefferred.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property IsPreferred() As Nullable(Of Global.System.Boolean)
        Get
            Return _IsPreferred
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Boolean))
            OnIsPreferredChanging(value)
            _IsPreferred = value
            OnIsPreferredChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnIsPreferredChanging(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Boolean))
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnIsPreferredChanged()
    End Sub
    #End Region

    #Region "EmailTypeL"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' EmailTypeL.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property EmailTypeL() As Global.System.String
        Get
            Return _EmailTypeL
        End Get
        Set(value As Global.System.String)
            OnEmailTypeLChanging(value)
            _EmailTypeL = value
            OnEmailTypeLChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnEmailTypeLChanging(value As Global.System.String)
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnEmailTypeLChanged()
    End Sub
    #End Region

    #Region "EmailTypsS"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' EmailTypeS.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property EmailTypeS() As Global.System.String
        Get
            Return _EmailTypeS
        End Get
        Set(value As Global.System.String)
            OnEmailTypeSChanging(value)
            _EmailTypeS = value
            OnEmailTypeSChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnEmailTypeSChanging(value As Global.System.String)
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnEmailTypeSChanged()
    End Sub
    #End Region

    #Region "EmailAddress"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' EmailAddress.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property EmailAddress() As Global.System.String
        Get
            Return _EmailAddress
        End Get
        Set(value As Global.System.String)
            OnEmailAddressChanging(value)
            _EmailAddress = value
            OnEmailAddressChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnEmailAddressChanging(value As Global.System.String)
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnEmailAddressChanged()
    End Sub
    #End Region

    #Region "EID"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' EID.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property EID() As Global.System.Int32
        Get
            Return _EID
        End Get
        Set(value As Global.System.Int32)
            If (_EID <> value) Then
                OnEIDChanging(value)
                _EID = value
                OnEIDChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnEIDChanging(value As Global.System.Int32)
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnEIDChanged()
    End Sub
    #End Region

    #Region "XID"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' XID.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property XID() As Global.System.Int32
        Get
            Return _XID
        End Get
        Set(value As Global.System.Int32)
            If _XID <> value Then
                OnXIDChanging(value)
                _XID = value
                OnXIDChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnXIDChanging(value As Global.System.Int32)
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnXIDChanged()
    End Sub
    #End Region

    #End Region
End Class
#End Region

#Region "CompanyEmail"
''' <summary>
''' CompanyEmail class.
''' </summary>
<DataContractAttribute(IsReference:=True)>
Partial Public Class CompanyEmail
    Inherits Email

    #Region "Declarations"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Private _Company As Company
    #End Region

    #Region "Factory Method"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create a new CompanyEmail object.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="emailTypeL">Initial value of the EmailTypeL property.</param>
    ''' <param name="emailTypeS">Initial value of the EmailTypeS property.</param>
    ''' <param name="emailAddress">Initial value of the EmailAddress property.</param>
    ''' <param name="eID">Initial value of the EID property.</param>
    ''' <param name="xID">Initial value of the XID property.</param>
    Public Shared Function CreateCompanyEmail(emailTypeL As Global.System.String,             emailTypeS As Global.System.String, emailAddress As Global.System.String, eID As Global.System.Int32, xID As Global.System.Int32) As CompanyEmail
        Dim companyEmail As CompanyEmail = New CompanyEmail
        companyEmail.EmailTypeL = emailTypeL
        companyEmail.EmailTypeS = emailTypeS
        companyEmail.EmailAddress = emailAddress
        companyEmail.EID = eID
        companyEmail.XID = xID
        Return companyEmail
    End Function
    #End Region

    #Region "ParentProperties"
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property Company() As Company
        Get
            Return _Company
        End Get
        Set(value As Company)
            _Company = value
        End Set
    End Property
    #End Region
End Class
#End Region

#Region "CompanyLocEmail"
''' <summary>
''' CompanyLocEmail class.
''' </summary>
<DataContractAttribute(IsReference:=True)>
Partial Public Class CompanyLocEmail
    Inherits Email

    #Region "Declarations"
    Private _CompanyLoc As CompanyLoc
    #End Region

    #Region "Factory Method"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create a new CompanyLocEmail object.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="emailTypeL">Initial value of the EmailTypeL property.</param>
    ''' <param name="emailTypeS">Initial value of the EmailTypeS property.</param>
    ''' <param name="emailAddress">Initial value of the EmailAddress property.</param>
    ''' <param name="eID">Initial value of the EID property.</param>
    ''' <param name="xID">Initial value of the XID property.</param>
    Public Shared Function CreateCompanyLocEmail(emailTypeL As Global.System.String, emailTypeS As Global.System.String, emailAddress As Global.System.String, eID As Global.System.Int32, xID As Global.System.Int32) As CompanyLocEmail
        Dim companyLocEmail As CompanyLocEmail = New CompanyLocEmail
        companyLocEmail.EmailTypeL = emailTypeL
        companyLocEmail.EmailTypeS = emailTypeS
        companyLocEmail.EmailAddress = emailAddress
        companyLocEmail.EID = eID
        companyLocEmail.XID = xID
        Return companyLocEmail
    End Function
    #End Region

    #Region "ParentProperties"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property CompanyLoc() As CompanyLoc
        Get
            Return _CompanyLoc
        End Get
        Set(value As CompanyLoc)
            _CompanyLoc = value
        End Set
    End Property
    #End Region
End Class
#End Region

#Region "UserEmail"
''' <summary>
''' UserEmail class.
''' </summary>
<DataContractAttribute(IsReference:=True)>
Partial Public Class UserEmail
    Inherits Email

    #Region "Declarations"
    Private _UserRole As UserRole
    #End Region

    #Region "Factory Method"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create a new UserEmail object.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="emailTypeL">Initial value of the EmailTypeL property.</param>
    ''' <param name="emailTypeS">Initial value of the EmailTypeS property.</param>
    ''' <param name="emailAddress">Initial value of the EmailAddress property.</param>
    ''' <param name="eID">Initial value of the EID property.</param>
    ''' <param name="xID">Initial value of the XID property.</param>
    Public Shared Function CreateUserEmail(emailTypeL As Global.System.String, emailTypeS As Global.System.String, emailAddress As Global.System.String, eID As Global.System.Int32, xID As Global.System.Int32) As UserEmail
        Dim userEmail As UserEmail = New UserEmail
        userEmail.EmailTypeL = emailTypeL
        userEmail.EmailTypeS = emailTypeS
        userEmail.EmailAddress = emailAddress
        userEmail.EID = eID
        userEmail.XID = xID
        Return userEmail
    End Function
    #End Region

    #Region "ParentProperties"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property UserRole() As UserRole
        Get
            Return _UserRole
        End Get
        Set(value As UserRole)
            _UserRole = value
        End Set
    End Property
    #End Region
End Class
#End Region
```

Interface definition

```
<OperationContract()> _
Function GetEmail(iID As Integer) As UserEmail
```

Actual Call

```
    Public Function GetEmail(iID As Integer) As UserEmail Implements InsightDataAPIInterface.GetEmail
    Dim ret = (From c In db.Emails Where c.EID = iID Select c).Take(1)
    Dim y As UserEmail
    For Each x In ret
        y = CType(x, UserEmail)
    Next x
    'Breakpoint  here shows correct data in y, so y returns the class
    Return y
End Function
```

This will not be the final iteration of GetEmail, but I am using this in it's current state to try and figure out why I am not getting the class to serialize correctly. If anyone could nudge me in the correct direction I would be greatly in their debt. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Namespace property in your `<DataContract>` declaration. In Visual Basic I've seen many cases where the Root Namespace property of the client / server projects are different (they default to the project name, which are expected to be different) - and the root namespace ends up being used to define the CLR namespace of the classes. if the namespace of a data contract is not explicitly set, then WCF will use the CLR namespace, and if the client / server classes are in different namespaces, you'll see an error like the one you have.

```
<DataContractAttribute(IsReference:=True, Namespace:="http://my.namespace.com")>
```

Comment: The problem wasn't with the actual class itself, the serialazation wasn't happening because the multiplicity on the EDM was 1->* instead of 0..1->* for the dependent classes.

Comment: Are you saying you've fixed the problem now?

Comment: I thought I had, but turns out, that wasn't the issue. So no, it's still broken. :(

Comment: It appears as though there is a problem with the associations in the edm. I stripped the model down to bare nothing and with no associations, the email will return. Too weird.

Comment: Figured out the problem. The POCO was being created as a proxy so adding db.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = False to the code fixed the issue.